# How programatically remove the data which copied from assets from my emulator in android?

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I wrote an android app that copy database from assets folder on following path:

```
DB_PATH = String.format("//data//data//%s//databases//", packageName);
```

and after that manipulate data and save the changes on the database. Because app needs data that saved by end user on database I can't allow that copy multiple times the tables of database. Now I want released an update for my app and I need add two columns two one of my table.
By myself I make a copy of database on assets and add two columns and just rename it and rename the name of database in my app. Now when install my app work right but the data that saved in emulator get about twice. I just think maybe it is possible to delete previous data from emulator by a line in my app, is it possible?

Comment: "I wrote an android app that copy database from assets folder on following path" -- That is not the correct path in all situations. I **strongly** encourage you to [use `SQLiteAssetHelper`](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper) for packaging a database in your APK as an asset. If you insist on
using your own code, use `getDatabasePath()` -- **never hardcode root paths**.

Comment: `to delete previous data`. You mean to delete an old unused database file? Use File:delete();

Comment: @ CommonsWare: thank you for your help, but as I read the database upgrades part of project understood that it has same problem as me and make a new name for the updated database from  assets folder and copy it to the same folder as before. It is never delete previous version of database, isn't it? Or I am wrong?